# Cannot update properties of the owned side in a one-to-one relationship

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-security

I have a  User class and each user instance has a profile. The profile has an avatarImage property that I will like to update. I'm able to update fields of the user but not fields of the profile of that user at runtime. I am using springsecurity to get the currentUser and I want to update his avatarImage but I get an SQLException at runtime.

User Domain Class:

```
package com.clinton.kiitsocial

import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode
import groovy.transform.ToString

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes='username')
@ToString(includes='username', includeNames=true, includePackage=false)
class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

transient springSecurityService

//don't touch this...for spring-security
String username
String password
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

//starting custom domain...can touch this
Integer uniqueId
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated

static hasMany = [contents: Content]

static hasOne = [profile: Profile]


User(String username, String password) {
    this()
    this.username = username
    this.password = password
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this)*.role
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService?.passwordEncoder ? springSecurityService.encodePassword(password) : password
}

static transients = ['springSecurityService']

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false, minSize: 5, validator: { pass, user ->
        pass != user.username
    }
    uniqueId blank: false, unique: true, range: 1000..2000000000

    profile unique: true, nullable: true
    contents nullable: true
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
    profile fetch: 'join'
}
```

}

Profile Domain Class:

```
package com.clinton.kiitsocial

class Profile {
    String bio
    String contact
    String address
    GenderList gender
    String emailId
    Avatar avatarImage
    User user

    static hasMany = [socialNetworks: Social]

    static constraints = {
        bio nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        address nullable: true, maxSize: 50
        contact nullable: true, matches: "^\\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]\$"
        socialNetworks nullable: true, unique: true
        gender nullable: true, blank: false
        emailId email: true, blank: true
        avatarImage nullable: true
    }
}
```

UserController:

```
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER'])
class UserController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    def userService
    UserController() {
        super(User)
    }

    def uploadAvatar() {
        MultipartFile avatar = request.getFile('avatar')
        avatar ? respond (userService.uploadingAvatar(avatar)): respond (500)
    }

    def showAvatar() {
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
package com.clinton.kiitsocial

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile

@Transactional
class UserService {

    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService
    private static final acceptedAvatarTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif']

    User uploadingAvatar(MultipartFile file) {
        User user = (User) springSecurityService.currentUser
        Profile profile = Profile.findOrSaveByUser(user)
        assert profile.user.username == user.username
        //assert !profile.avatarImage
        String message = ""
        if (!acceptedAvatarTypes.contains(file.contentType)) {
            //message = "Avatar must be one of: ${acceptedAvatarTypes} type"
            //respond 500
            return user
        }
        profile.avatarImage = new Avatar(avatar: file.bytes, avatarType: file.contentType)
        println("uploading: ${profile.avatarImage.avatarType}")
        if (!profile.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)) { //Error ocurs here
            message = "error occurred saving image"
            println("${profile.errors}")
            //respond user.errors
            return user
        }
         message = "Avatar (${profile.avatarImage.avatarType}, ${profile.avatarImage.avatar.size()} bytes) uploaded."
         println(message)
        println("finishing...")
        return user
    }

    /*def showAvatar(long  userId) {
        def avatarUser = User.get(userId)
        if (!avatarUser || !avatarUser.profile.avatarImage || !avatarUser.profile.avatarType) {
            //respond 404
            return
        }
        response.contentType = avatarUser.profile.avatarType
        response.contentLength = avatarUser.profile.avatarImage.size()
        OutputStream out = response.outputStream
        out.write(avatarUser.profile.avatarImage)
        out.close()
    }*/
}
```

Error/Stacktrace:

> uploading: image/png 2016-12-17 12:27:48.668 ERROR ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Parameter
>   "#1" is not set; SQL statement: select this_.id as id1_3_0_,
>   this_.version as version2_3_0_, this_.address as address3_3_0_,
>   this_.avatar_image_id as avatar_i4_3_0_, this_.bio as bio5_3_0_,
>   this_.contact as contact6_3_0_, this_.email_id as email_id7_3_0_,
>   this_.gender as gender8_3_0_, this_.user_id as user_id9_3_0_ from
>   profile this_ where this_.id=? [90012-192] 2016-12-17 12:27:48.711
>   ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   :
>   JdbcSQLException occurred when processing request: [POST] /api/avatars
>   Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL statement: select this_.id as id1_3_0_,
>   this_.version as version2_3_0_, this_.address as address3_3_0_,
>   this_.avatar_image_id as avatar_i4_3_0_, this_.bio as bio5_3_0_,
>   this_.contact as contact6_3_0_, this_.email_id as email_id7_3_0_,
>   this_.gender as gender8_3_0_, this_.user_id as user_id9_3_0_ from
>   profile this_ where this_.id=? [90012-192]. Stacktrace follows:
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>           at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
>           at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
>           at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:143)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter.doFilter(RestLogoutFilter.groovy:80)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
>           at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.processFilterChain(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:118)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter.doFilter(RestTokenValidationFilter.groovy:84)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RestAuthenticationFilter.groovy:143)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>           at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
>           at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate
>   operation: could not extract ResultSet; uncategorized SQLException for
>   SQL [n/a]; SQL state [90012]; error code [90012]; Parameter "#1" is
>   not set; SQL statement: select this_.id as id1_3_0_, this_.version as
>   version2_3_0_, this_.address as address3_3_0_, this_.avatar_image_id
>   as avatar_i4_3_0_, this_.bio as bio5_3_0_, this_.contact as
>   contact6_3_0_, this_.email_id as email_id7_3_0_, this_.gender as
>   gender8_3_0_, this_.user_id as user_id9_3_0_ from profile this_ where
>   this_.id=? [90012-192]; nested exception is
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL
>   statement: select this_.id as id1_3_0_, this_.version as
>   version2_3_0_, this_.address as address3_3_0_, this_.avatar_image_id
>   as avatar_i4_3_0_, this_.bio as bio5_3_0_, this_.contact as
>   contact6_3_0_, this_.email_id as email_id7_3_0_, this_.gender as
>   gender8_3_0_, this_.user_id as user_id9_3_0_ from profile this_ where
>   this_.id=? [90012-192]
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertJdbcAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:668)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:656)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:247)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:187)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:110)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.UniqueConstraint.processValidate(UniqueConstraint.java:149)
>           at grails.validation.AbstractConstraint.validate(AbstractConstraint.java:107)
>           at grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty.validate(ConstrainedProperty.java:979)
>           at org.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validatePropertyWithConstraint(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:211)
>           at org.grails.validation.GrailsDomainClassValidator.validate(GrailsDomainClassValidator.java:81)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:122)
>           at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
>           at com.clinton.kiitsocial.UserService$$EQ5cdaRc.$tt__uploadingAvatar(UserService.groovy:26)
>           at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
>           at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
>           at com.clinton.kiitsocial.UserController$$EQ5ccaGm.uploadAvatar(UserController.groovy:20)
>           ... 38 common frames omitted Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "#1" is not set; SQL
>   statement: select this_.id as id1_3_0_, this_.version as
>   version2_3_0_, this_.address as address3_3_0_, this_.avatar_image_id
>   as avatar_i4_3_0_, this_.bio as bio5_3_0_, this_.contact as
>   contact6_3_0_, this_.email_id as email_id7_3_0_, this_.gender as
>   gender8_3_0_, this_.user_id as user_id9_3_0_ from profile this_ where
>   this_.id=? [90012-192]
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
>           at org.h2.expression.Parameter.checkSet(Parameter.java:81)
>           at org.h2.command.Prepared.checkParameters(Prepared.java:164)
>           at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:109)
>           at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201)
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:110)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2122)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1905)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.UniqueConstraint$2.call(UniqueConstraint.java:210)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.validation.UniqueConstraint$2.call(UniqueConstraint.java:149)
>           at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
>           ... 52 common frames omitted

I have spent 2 days trying to fix this problem. All suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your time..

Comment: Did you try to run `profile.validate()` before 26 line in `UserService` and debug it?

Comment: I figured it out. I run integration tests on it and figured that, hibernate needs inner domains to be persisted and flushed before attaching them to a parent domain. Like bottom up fashion. See answer below...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I run integration tests on it and figured that: hibernate needs inner domains to be persisted and flushed before attaching them to a parent domain. Like bottom up fashion. See answer below. It was caused by transient domain instance.

```
Avatar uploadingAvatar(MultipartFile file) {
        User user = (User) springSecurityService.currentUser
        if (!user.profile) user.profile = new Profile(user: user).save(flush: true)
        if (!acceptedAvatarTypes.contains(file.contentType)) {
            responseCode = 500
        }

        Avatar avatar = user.profile.avatarImage ?: new Avatar()
        avatar.avatarName = file.originalFilename
        avatar.avatarBytes = file.bytes
        avatar.avatarType = file.contentType
        if (!avatar.validate() && !avatar.save(flush: true)){
            responseCode = 500
            return avatar
        }
        user.profile.avatarImage = avatar
        println("Avatar changed success")
        responseCode = 200
        return avatar
    }
```